# Battlefield 4 is unbelievably laggy, is there any way I can fix it?

Tags: battlefield-4

I played just a few days ago, and everything was pretty good. Got a couple of semi-laggy servers, but I figured they were in different countries.

But today, I have experienced the worst lag in all the time I've played BF4 (to be fair I've only been playing a month or two, but still). I found a few lobbies with 4 bars, but upon joining I'm shown that there are multiple connection issues occurring. The last game I played had three severe warnings immediately shown to me as I joined in, so I left. Whenever I join a lobby and run a few feet, I am immediately rubber-banded backward. As I watch the game from the game menu (what you're brought to when you die, I'm not sure what it's called) every so often every person pauses at the same time (lag strike, yippee) before moving again.

I am almost completely unable to play Battlefield right now. I *have* tested my internet connection and connection in PS4, and both say everything is fine and dandy.

Are the EA servers weird right now? Should I try resetting my internet? Should I just try to play tomorrow?

Answer (score -1):

One of the possibilities is that one or more of the players in your lobby has a very high PING, which is causing the lag. Otherwise, it could be your own PING. This could be caused by another family member in your house using the internet to download things, watch Netflix, or stream videos, which can really slow the internet down, because it eats at your bandwidth. By ensuring nobody else is doing these while you're playing, it should reduce PING and stop the lag.

Other than that, you could switch from a wireless connection to a wired connection, which usually strengthens the connection. You could also close any background running apps.

Also, try and play in servers close to your location. Playing in servers far from your location can cause lag in the game and reduce performance.

I would reset the internet and keep it off for a while before turning back on, giving it some time to refresh.